# Spring Cloud Gateway Logging of Request and Response using filter

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway, global-filter

```
Spring Cloud Gateway global filter throwing **Only one connection receive subscriber allowed.** when logging response from getting exchange.
```

Getting response from ServerWebExchange

```
Connection connection = exchange.getAttribute(CLIENT_RESPONSE_CONN_ATTR);
```

After getting connection object to get NettyDataBuffer

```
    Flux<NettyDataBuffer> bodyNettyDataBuffer = connection.inbound().receive().retain().map(factory::wrap);
```

Then Subscriber to log request and it is failing here

```
bodyNettyDataBuffer.subscribe(buffer -> {
```

Initializing byte array

```
                byte[] dst = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
```

slice to buffer to get byter array value

```
                buffer.getNativeBuffer().slice().getBytes(0, dst);
```

converting into string and logging

```
                LOGGER.info("Response Body:{}", new String(dst));
            });
```

Comment: This is already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117061/springcloudgateway-log-incoming-request-url-and-corresponding-route-uri

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SpringCloudGateway - Log incoming request url and corresponding route URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54117061/springcloudgateway-log-incoming-request-url-and-corresponding-route-uri)

Comment: Using spring cloud gateway 2.1.2 and using custom logging  instead of spring boot logging. But not working for me.                                                                 
  <Logger level="TRACE" name="org.springframework.cloud.gateway">
   <AppenderRef ref="spring-req-res"
    additivity="${additivity}" />
  </Logger>
  
  <Logger level="INFO" name="reactor.netty.http" />